# How to theme Android Material Theme UI Elements with Appcelerator?

Tags: android, user-interface, themes, appcelerator

There is this useful information and everything works well:
http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Android_Themes

The image is also very helpful: [image]

The problem is that I want to have white or very light gray in the top bar. When I set this as "android:textColorPrimary", however, the text is white in the top bar, but in all alerts for instance as well making it invisible/very difficult to read.

How can I set the text color of the bar to white and theme the alert messages and other text in the default text color (dark gray)?

The themeAndroid.xml in app/platform/android/res/values looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<style name="materialTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorPrimary">#2e7d32</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#005005</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#80d8ff</item>
    <item name="colorSwitchThumbNormal">#49a7cc</item>
    <item name="android:colorButtonNormal">#49a7cc</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#DADADA</item>
    <item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">@style/SpinnerItem</item>
    <item name="android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/SpinnerDropDownItem</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to style the color of the actionbar font you need to extend your theme like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="Theme.MyThemeActionbar" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="colorPrimary">#FF0000</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#000000</item>

        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/CustomTheme.ActionBarStyle</item>
        <item name="actionBarTheme">@style/Theme.ActionBarTheme</item>

        <!-- tab -->
        <item name="actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/TabStyle</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/TabStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.ActionBarTheme" parent="style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar">
        <!-- actionbar arrow -->
        <item name="colorControlNormal">#ffffff</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CustomTheme.ActionBarStyle" parent="style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <!-- actionbar -->
        <item name="elevation">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">#FFFFFF</item>
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/CustomTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
        <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/CustomTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CustomTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
        <!-- actionbar font -->
        <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
    </style>

    <style name="TabStyle" parent="style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.TabText">
        <!-- tab font -->
        <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Then you can set the font color and the primary color to a different value and leave other thinks to the default values

Comment: Thanks for the tip about extending the theme! Works great changed the title in the action bar. Is there a way to target the color of the tab titles and set them to white? This <Tab color="white"> in views.xml does not work for instance.

Comment: added the tab font in my example above